How to make this code perform smooth image transition + problem
I use this code to make the background image of the page alternate:


.hero {
    position: relative; 
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.hero::before {    
      content: "";
      /*background-size: cover;*/
      background-repeat: auto;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0px;
      right: 0px;
      bottom: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      opacity: 0.3;   
      background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/11/Louis-le-Grand--cour-honneur.jpg/800px-Louis-le-Grand--cour-honneur.jpg);
      animation-name: changing;
      animation-duration: 6s;
      animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@keyframes changing {
  from {background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/11/Louis-le-Grand--cour-honneur.jpg/800px-Louis-le-Grand--cour-honneur.jpg);}
  50% {background-image: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/e8/E._Marcellot_Sim%C3%A9on-Denis_Poisson_1804.jpg/800px-E._Marcellot_Sim%C3%A9on-Denis_Poisson_1804.jpg);}
}


h1 {
  position: relative;
  color: #ffffff;  
  font-size: 3em;
  line-height: 0.9;
  text-align: center;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=5.0, user-scalable=yes" uw-rm-meta-viewport="">

</head>

<body>

<div class="hero">
  <h1>Hello world</h1>
</div>

</body>

</html>



I have two questions:

In the firefox browser, the code does what it has to, the images alternate after 3 seconds.
In chrome, the images also alternate, but in a quite different manner: the transition between images is smooth, while it occurs with a kind of rotation of the images. How can I prevent this rotation?

I would like a modification of the above code that work identically for most common browsers, and that have features from both behavior: in one hand, smooth image transitions, and in the other hand no weird rotation effect during the transition.



With "rotation" do you mean that the size of the images slowly changes while fading? If yes, then you probably want to use two images with the same size (or probably at least same aspect ratio)

I think you may have the point. So, why different aspect ratio behave well in Firefox and not in Chrome?

Because background-image is not an animatable property. The comments below this answer go more in detail.

Resizing the image to the same size works to kill the resizing effect. Now, it remains to understand how to make the transition smooth for Firefox.
